# Dropdown como filtros Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo un dropdron que me muestra los datos que quiero filtrar, cuando yo seleccione uno de esos en la vista se deberia llevar a cabo el filtro, pero  he probado varias cosas y no me ha funcionado, pueden ayudarme, se me ocurre que deba hacer una funcion que cuando haga click me filtre.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
    <mat-label> <mat-icon>search</mat-icon> Buscar por usuario</mat-label>
    <mat-select matNativeControl >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let current of currentHistory" [value]="current.registerBy" (click)="filter(current)">
            {{current.registerBy}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

lo podria hacer asi con ngModel

```
      <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
        <mat-label> <mat-icon>search</mat-icon> Buscar por usuario</mat-label>
        <mat-select [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="userRegisterBy"
        (ngModelChange)="dataChanged($event)" >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let current of currentHistory" [value]="current.registerBy" >
                {{current.registerBy}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

y crearias la variable y la funcion que se ejecutaria cada vez que elijan una opcion diferente en el select

```
userRegisterBy!: any;

  dataChanged(newObj: any) {
    console.log(this.userRegisterBy);
  }
```

espero te ayude, NO TE RINDAS!!!